# VSS Not Creating Shadow Set

Tags: backup, windows-xp, vss

I'm trying to setup backup scripts on WinXP to use Volume Shadow Sets.  I downloaded the VSS 7.2 SDK from MSFT, and used the include `vshadow.exe` to create a shadow set:

```
vshadow -script=vss-setvar.cmd f:
```

(note that I've tried both f: and c:)

`vshadow` executes just find, giving no errors, reporting the shadow is created.  However, executing

```
vshadow -q
```

as the very next command results in "There are no shadows on the system" and, indeed, if I use `dosdev` to try and map the Shadow set named in `vss-setvar.cmd`, it will not work.

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the web page at: http://blogs.msdn.com/adioltean/archive/2005/01/05/346793.aspx , when vshadow is run on an XP system, the Shadow Volume is deleted when the command finishes running. To be able to use the shadow volume, you must use a callback script (add -exec=Callback-script.cmd to your command line and put the actions to preform on the shadow volume in that scipt.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the place where you are creating the shadow copy is NTFS, and not FAT16/FAT32.

You can double check this by right click the parition/drive and going to properties.

<strike>Also you may wish to see if that tool is supported under Windows XP.  You may need to upgrade to either Windows Server line or possibly Vista, but I don't have details on that.</strike>

Never mind, according to the [tool download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0b4f56e4-0ccc-4626-826a-ed2c4c95c871&displaylang=en#Requirements) Windows XP is supported.

<strike>Also to create a shadow copy the command is</strike>

```
vssadmin create shadow /for=c:
```

You may wish to look at the MSDN support documents about the VSS tools.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530725(VS.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384631(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Yep, c: and f: are NTFS.  There is no vssadmin.exe anywhere in the VSS SDK that I've downloaded (and that you've linked to), however.

Comment: I've linked to more information about vshadow, and some diagnostic tools for VSS that may give you some more insight into what's going on.